# Rate control star for rating purpose in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am working on rate control for my project, where user can rate pictures. So I need rate control star for rating purpose. When I searched about it I found this [Link]http://wp7wonders.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/use-the-rating-control-in-windows-phone-7/ and [Link]http://j4ni.com/blog/?p=79 .First link was not so helpful i was able to create star but not able to fetch the rating numbers like 3/5 or 2/5 e.t.c. Second link I was able to create star but I was not able to see the stars on emulator screen but when I clicked the area where I kept the stars I was able to view the stars which I clicked. Is there any other way to do it. It will be a help to understand Windows phone as I am new to windows phone framework.

Answer (score 0):

In your first link each ratingitem control has a property called DisplayValue which is either 0 or 1. When its set to 1 it means its selected. If you check each of the ratingitem's you can get a number. The actual rating control ControlsToolkit:Rating has a Value property
which is the number you're looking for.

for example.

Adding 
`<ControlsToolkit:Rating Height="40" Grid.Row="1" Value="0.6" ItemCount="0" x:Name="ctRating">` 
in the code behind you can check the ctRating.Value selecting all 5 gives you a 1.0 value

Comment: thanks for reply. let me check if it works I would let you know.. :)

Comment: @Wingen its not working I tried to get the value but I am getting 0.6666 kind of value I want if user click 1st star I should get 1 as a rating or if user click 2nd star i should get 2 as rating like this way if user click 5th star i should get 5 as a rating.. if you have any other suggestion it would be a help. I am still searching answers. Otherwise there is another way to do and that is I should have one fill and unfill star image when user click the unfill star it should get fill and return a value 1. All this is possible using click event.

Comment: you could figure out the number they clicked by  5 * ctRating.Value. should give you the number you're looking for.. and you can round the number if need be.

Comment: thanks for your reply but I am still not got the answer can you please suggest me some other answer or any library...